# Phrase Search using Elasticsearch Showing Unrelated Results

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.4.1 on an Ubuntu Linux machine to provide search for a Django 1.5 site, using Haystack 2.3.1.  I have my search indexes set up using EdgeNGram fields for the document text, and other than some filtering of the searchqueryset in the SearchView, I have a pretty standard setup (I think :) ).

What I'm having an issue with is that phrase searches (quoted searches) are working fine, except for some certain cases, for example: "1G chicken" (just made up, but exemplifies the issue) - what it seems to do is ignore the 1G and simply turn it into a search for "chicken".  Is this expected?  Is there a way to force elastic search to honor the phrase?

Here is the query itself from the slow log:

```
[2014-12-09 17:09:19,373][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.fetch] [Advisor] [haystack][4] took[3.3ms], took_millis[3], types[modelresult], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"terms":{"django_ct":["objectives.objective","actions.action","attachments.file","projects.project","toolkits.toolkit"]}},"query":{"query_string":{"auto_generate_phrase_queries":true,"default_operator":"AND","analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"(organization_id:(\"2\" OR \"3\" OR \"6\" OR \"40\" OR \"170\" OR \"171\" OR \"172\" OR \"173\" OR \"174\") AND (\"1G Chicken\"))","default_field":"text"}}}},"from":0,"size":15}], extra_source[],
```

The "organization_id" is related to the SQS filtering in the SearchView that I mentioned originally.

Also note I've tried things like manually setting the fuzziness to 0, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: What settings have you used for you EdgeNGram analyser?

Comment: This is the default Haystack edge n-gram settings, so looking at the backend it seems:

tokenizer: lowercase
min_gram: 3
max_gram: 15

Could it be that it's throwing out the 1G part?

Comment: yes :-)  min_gram: 3 will ignore everything less than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A min_gram of three will only store tokens with three characters or more - "1G" will be ignored.

You can either decrease the min_gram to smaller length or switch to another analyser.

Comment: Heh, sounds so obvious when you put it like that!  :)  I hadn't even thought to look at the settings there.