# Elasticsearch Phrase Search Yields Unexpected Results

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.4.1 on an Ubuntu Linux machine to provide search for a Django 1.5 site, using Haystack 2.3.1. I have my search indexes set up using EdgeNGram fields for the document text, and other than some filtering of the searchqueryset in the SearchView, I have a pretty standard setup (I think :) ), other than setting the hardcoded min_gram settings in the haystack backend to be 1.

This question is a follow up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484918/phrase-search-using-elasticsearch-showing-unrelated-results) I asked (and which was answered, thanks stack overflow!),  but I recognize the behavior I am/was seeing is related to two issues.  The first was related to min_gram not allowing short tokens to be indexed, that's fixed now.

The next issue I'm seeing relates to the length of a phrase query seemingly differentiating how it's treated.  Silly example to show this (with min_gram to 1):

Phrase query "1 A abc de fghijk" will yield exactly what you expect - just documents that contain exactly that phrase.

Phrase query "1 A abc", however, will return documents with a 1, an A or abc it seems, more like a non-phrase search.

Is there different analyzing/handling of queries in elastic search based on their length? If so, is there a way to change that minimum?  If not, any ideas on what else could be causing this behavior? I don't see anything in the docs suggesting that, but obviously there's a whole lot in the docs, maybe I missed something.

Comment: What do you get when you put your data and your search queries through your Edge nGram analyser e.g.: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=cust_analyser' -d '1 A abc de fghij'

Comment: No real difference between the two, other than of course that the one is shorter.  I've created a gist containing the output: https://gist.github.com/jimjkelly/6267df04978fc90e2524

Comment: Have you got an example of a field that matches against "1 A abc" but doesn't contain "abc"?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm seeing.  The highlighting on the returned result implies its matching on "a".

Comment: Also, thanks so much for your help on this and the previous question!

Comment: based on the tokens that the search string is broken down into - there is no "1" and as "abc" gets broken down into "a", "ab", "abc" it could match with lots of values.  EdgeNGram is great as a word suggester or auto-complete - not really suitable for phrase searching though.

Comment: Well I guess that's the central part of my confusion - haystack says in the docs that it's auto query method handles phrase searches, but I'm not seeing much of a difference in what it does, on the elastic search side it looks as if haystack is just pushing everything through as a query_string, and it seems to me when I pass a quoted string it does a phrase search for longer phrases and the edgengram analysis for smaller stuff. If it were doing edgengram all the time, I wouldn't be seeing just the one result when searching for '1 A abc de fghij', right?